# Redirecting a url with a shtml extension to a php extension with htacess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have many old .shtml files in a subdomain of my main site that have been updated. The updated files are however, php files that have the same names of the original files and are also in the same location. for example /processing/myfile.shtml is the old version of /processing/myfile.php

I'd like to ensure that when a visitor tries to access the .shtml file that they are redirected to the equivalent .php file. I have been informed that I can only do this through htaccess as I am utilizing shared hosting.

However adding the following to htaccess does not work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^processing\.lyndondaniels\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.processing\.lyndondaniels\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.shtml$ "http\:\/\/processing\.lyndondaniels\.com\/$1.php" [R=301,L]
```

I'm kinda just winging it as I'm unfamilliar with the syntax, so I'd appreciate it if you could provide me with a working example. thanks!

Comment: This rule should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.shtml$ "http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.php" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Great Thanks NaijaProgrammer this answer works for me :)